# Fonts randomly stop rendering correctly when building with Xcode 15

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, xcode15

After updating my/our devices to iOS 17 (or Xcode 15, not entirely sure), the custom fonts in our application have started **randomly** not working. Usually it will happen after the app has been in the background for a while, I think.

I'm aware that there's been problems with Xcode 15 and fonts in Interface Builder, but (thankfully) we don't use that at all.

What happens is either:

1. The fonts don't load at all. For icon fonts, this means a lot of question marks.
2. The fonts get swapped around, meaning regular text (Roboto, custom font) starts rendering using the icon font (Font Awesome). I can tell because I recognize the font from when incorrectly putting text into an icon during development. I tried the memory warning on the simulator, but that doesn't trigger it. It did not happen when building for iOS 16 and I did not change any font logic since then. It still does not happen on devices running iOS 17 but on versions of the app built with Xcode 14.

These are potentially the same problem, as attempting to load icons with a non-icon font would trigger situation #1. I have not been able to attach a debugger to inspect the views as I cannot reproduce the error.

Some debug info:

Xcode: 15.0.1 (15A507)

iOS: 17.1.1 (real device, I have not observed it on Simulator)

We load the custom fonts from a proprietary SPM package:

```swift
fileprivate static func registerFont(fontName: String, ext: String = "otf") {
    
    guard let fontURL = Bundle.module.url(forResource: fontName, withExtension: ext),
        let fontDataProvider = CGDataProvider(url: fontURL as CFURL),
        let font = CGFont(fontDataProvider) else {
            fatalError("Couldn't create font from filename: \(fontName).\(ext)")
    }
    
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?

    CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)
    
}

public static func registerFonts() {

    registerFont(fontName: "Font Awesome 6 Brands-Regular-400")
    registerFont(fontName: "Font Awesome 6 Duotone-Solid-900")
    registerFont(fontName: "Font Awesome 6 Pro-Light-300")
    registerFont(fontName: "Font Awesome 6 Pro-Regular-400")
    registerFont(fontName: "Font Awesome 6 Pro-Solid-900")
    registerFont(fontName: "Font Awesome 6 Pro-Thin-100")
    registerFont(fontName: "Font Awesome 6 Sharp-Light-300")
    registerFont(fontName: "Font Awesome 6 Sharp-Regular-400")
    registerFont(fontName: "Font Awesome 6 Sharp-Solid-900")
    registerFont(fontName: "Roboto-Medium", ext: "ttf")
    registerFont(fontName: "Roboto-Regular", ext: "ttf")
    registerFont(fontName: "RobotoMono-Regular", ext: "ttf")
    
}

// Similar methods for all font types and icons:
@objc public static func getDefaultFont(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {

    return UIFont.init(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: size) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: size);

}
```

This code is then called in `didFinishLaunching`, and it would crash the app if it failed:

```swift
FontHandler.registerFonts()
```

To reiterate, all the fonts work **when launching the app**. Restarting the app **always** fixes it, which, combined with the fact that they get swapped around, leads me to believe that it's some kind of font caching issue/bug.

We use the fonts in code-only (no storyboards or xibs ever). A font would be loaded like this:

```swift
let label = UILabel()
label.font = FontHandler.getDefaultFont(size: 15)
```

The font files themselves ship with the SPM package (in a folder called `Fonts`), which contains the `FontHandler` class used above.

```swift
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackageName",
    defaultLocalization: "en",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v11)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyPackageName",
            targets: ["MyPackageName"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyPackageName",
            resources: [
                .process("Fonts") // Here!
            ]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyPackageNameTests",
            dependencies: ["MyPackageName"]),
    ]
)
```